# Can I delete an Office 365 Group but keep the SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, recycle-bin

I have been asked to investigate this so I have also been running an experiment using PnP PowerShell commands:

```
$MyTempGroup = Get-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity $displayName
$MyTempGroup.SiteUrl
Remove-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity $displayName
$MytempGroup = Get-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity $displayName
// Has it gone yet
$MyTempGroup -eq $null
```

The idea is can restore just the SharePoint site from the recycle bin or will I get the whole group? My theory this won't be possible because the GROUP#0 template used to create the site wouldn't be valid if the group is present. Are there any clever workarounds to restore just the site.

Comment: I have done something similar and documented it here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249092/remove-office365-group-connection-from-site-collection/249101#249101

Comment: Thanks @susan ( H? ),  . I still have site up, even after 30 hours so no need to think about recycle bins. Will need to do further experiments, such as deleting MS Teams and sites with more active users

Comment: at the end of the day it is possible, I have done it with the help of a microsoft engineer but i believe the powershell script can be found, just you might not like the result, there were automatic links in the site to take you to the group that gave you 'file not found', not a good end user experience

Comment: I tried the same PS script on a Office 365 group that was created as part of MS Teams. This time both the Group and site were deleted immediately.